# config Eigen in CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

When I config Eigen library in CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(helloworld)

add_subdirectory(tests)
add_subdirectory(deps/eigen) 

set(SRC_LIST main.cpp)
add_executable(hello ${SRC_LIST})
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
target_link_libraries(hello eigen)
```

I got the cmake error as

```
CMake Error at build/deps/eigen/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  The file

    /Users/joe/codecplus/build/deps/eigen/Eigen3Targets.cmake

  was generated by the export() command.  It may not be used as the argument
  to the include() command.  Use ALIAS targets instead to refer to targets by
  alternative names.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

Can anybody help me out? Don't know what is going wrong here. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use **two ways** for including 3d-party project (Eigen) at the **same time**:

1. `add_subdirectory()`
2. `find_package()`

This is wrong. Resort to a single way:

1. With `add_subdirectory` only:

   ```
   add_subdirectory(deps/eigen) 
   # ...
   target_link_libraries(hello Eigen3::eigen)
   ```
2. With `find_package()` only:

   ```
   find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
   target_link_libraries(hello Eigen3::eigen)
   ```

Note, that both approaches uses `Eigen3::eigen` target instead of `eigen` for link with. Only this name works with the second approach, and it is described in the documentation for Eigen usage.

Comment: When using `find_package()` in config mode, is CMake smart enough to know to look in the build tree subdirectories, as this is where the file it's looking for (Eigen3Config.cmake) is generated? If not, will it not just look in the default directories where you could have two possible outcomes: it doesn't find the file at all, or it finds and uses the library installed on the system, rather than the one bundled with the project?

Comment: @Pesho_T: "... is CMake smart enough to know to look in the build tree subdirectories" - No, CMake doesn't search in the build tree automatically. Actually, it is [export(PACKAGE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/export.html) command flow which stores path to the package script (`/Users/joe/codecplus/build/deps/eigen/Eigen3Targets.cmake` in the given case) into the "CMake user package registry". Among other places, `find_package` searches a package in this registry. So, `find_package` would find Eigen package even if Eigen is built **separately** from the main project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Another question about your answer is, what "eigen" in `target_link_libraries(hello eigen)` is? Is it just the folder name of `deps/eigen` or some library name?  Because I did not find any files named as `eigen` in the deps/eigen directory and its all subdirectories?

Comment: @Jeff: `eigen` is a **target** for [INTERFACE library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries). It is created with [add_library (eigen INTERFACE)](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L583) and linking with it **automatically** adds include directories and other flags needed for use Eigen library. Actually, it is better to use `Eigen3::eigen` target: it is defined not only with `add_subdirectory` approach, but with `find_package()` too. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much for your help. "Actually, it is export(PACKAGE) command flow which stores path to the package script (/Users/joe/codecplus/build/deps/eigen/Eigen3Targets.cmake in the given case) into the "CMake user package registry"." When does this happen? Is it at the time when external package (Eigen) is build?

Comment: The project is exported when `export(PACKAGE)` is used. Eigen project uses this call [there](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L619).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry to bother you so much. The second way works perfect, but I tried the first way with `target_link_libraries(hello_world Eigen3::Eigen)`. It has a error `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (add_executable):
  Target "hello" links to target "Eigen3::Eigen" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?`. Do you know what's going on here? Why `target_link_libraries(hello_world eigen)` works but not for `target_link_libraries(hello_world Eigen3::Eigen).`?

Comment: Targets' names are case-**sensitive**: Correct name of the target is `Eigen3::eigen`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: "Actually, it is export(PACKAGE) command flow which stores path to the package script": so, if add_subdirectory(eigen) was not used, or the Eigen project was not build separately, find_package() would not work, correct?

Comment: @Pesho_T: Without `export(PACKAGE)` being executed `find_package()` won't find `Eigen3` config script in the *build* directory *automatically*. But it may the script with appropriate hint (e.g. via setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable) or find the script in other directories (e.g. under *system-wide* installation of Eigen3).